# Call of overloaded is ambiguous при реализации своего алгоритма copy

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, stl

Есть самописное подобие stl. Суть задачи - вектор пар (тоже самописные).

Проблема появилась при попытке создать вектор с парами при включении в пару `std::string`. Заругалось на неоднозначность:

```
ошибка: call of overloaded 'copy(vector<pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >::iterator, vector<pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >::iterator, pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*&)' is ambiguous
         copy(begin(), end(), newMemory);
         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Заменяю `copy(begin(), ...` на `std::copy(begin(), ...`, и все компилируется.

Реализация алгоритма `copy` скопирована [справочника](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/?kw=copy). Там заявлено:

> The behavior of this function template is equivalent to

то есть

> поведение шаблона функции эквивалентно коду, приведенному ниже

В итоге, не могу понять, что не так с алгоритмом `copy`, взятым из справочника. Почему он не переваривает `std::string` если заявлено, что его поведение эквивалентно `std::copy`?

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T1, class T2>
class pair
{
public:
    pair() :
        first(T1()),
        second(T2())
    {
    }

    pair(T1 _first, T2 _second) :
        first(_first),
        second(_second)
    {
    }


    T1 first;
    T2 second;
};

template<class MyInputIterator, class MyOutputIterator>
MyOutputIterator copy(MyInputIterator first, MyInputIterator last, MyOutputIterator result)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *result = *first;
        ++result; ++first;
    }
    return result;
}

template<class T>
class vector
{
public:
    vector() : _data(nullptr), _size(0) {}

    void push_back(const T &val)
    {
        reserve(_size + 1);
        _data[_size] = val;
        _size += 1;
    }

    void reserve(size_t n)
    {
        if (n > _size)
        {
            T *_newData = new T[_size + 1];

            if (_data) 
            {
                copy(begin(), end(), _newData);  //<<< ругается здесь
                delete [] _data;
            }

            _data = _newData;
        }
    }

    T* begin() { return _data; }
    T* end() { return _data + _size; }

private:
    T *_data;
    size_t _size;
};

int main()
{
    vector<pair<std::string, int>> v;
    v.push_back(pair<std::string, int>("qwerty", 5));

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Это что-то вроде тренировки на кошках (во избежание комментариев типа "зачем всё это надо, если есть stl").

Comment: Приведите сообщение об ошибке полностью

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если тип аргумента функции является специализацией шаблонного класса, то в список *ассоциированных пространств имен* для выполнения ADL будут включены также пространства имен, ассоциированные с типами шаблонных аргументов (см. http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2.2). В вашем случае один из шаблонных аргументов принадлежит пространству `std`. Из-за этого ADL будет рассматривать `std` как ассоциированное пространство имен и выполнять там поиск.

В результате ваше `copy` конкурирует с `std::copy`.

Либо переименуйте свою функцию, либо используйте квалифицированное имя для вызова функции: `::copy` (либо, если уж взялись, пишите свой `string` :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Замените название функции на какое-нибудь другое.

Из-за [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), при вызове `copy(...)` компилятор в вашем случае находит не только вашу `copy`, но и `std::copy`, и не может выбрать между ними.

Comment: С чего это ADL найдет тут std::copy, если аргументы - указатели на объекты из глобального пространства?

Comment: @VTT Там указатели на `std::pair`, поэтому компилятор и залезает в `std`.

Comment: Там указатели на самодельный `::pair`, описанный в начале примера

Comment: @VTT Пардон, не увидел. Ну тогда потому, что у него `std::string` в шаблонных параметрах.

Comment: ADL ищет намного глубже. Если у вас аргументы - шаблонного типа, то все аргументы шаблона тоже становятся источником associated namespaces для ADL. Там `std::string` среди аргументов шаблона фигурирует? Фигурирует. Получите `std` через ADL.